# EMCECS / ecs-object-client-java Trouble sending ObjectRetention request

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm using the ECM Java SDK to interact with our DELL S3 storage and am trying to set an ObjectRetention with the following code:

```java
public void putRetentionTimeOnObjectEcm(String bucket, String key, Date date){
        var request = new com.emc.object.s3.request.SetObjectRetentionRequest(bucket,key)
                .withRetention(new com.emc.object.s3.bean.ObjectLockRetention()
                        .withMode(com.emc.object.s3.bean.ObjectLockRetentionMode.GOVERNANCE)
                        .withRetainUntilDate(date));

        ecmS3Client.setObjectRetention(request);
    }
```

This somehow doesn't work and I get the following error:

`com.emc.object.s3.S3Exception: This happens when the user sends an empty xml document as a request. The error message is, "Request body is empty." at com.emc.object.s3.jersey.ErrorFilter.parseErrorResponse(ErrorFilter.java:134) at com.emc.object.s3.jersey.ErrorFilter.handle(ErrorFilter.java:69) at com.emc.object.s3.jersey.RetryFilter.handle(RetryFilter.java:65) ...`

I've looked at the documentation which wasan't very helpful.
When I call `request.getContentLength()` it returns `null`.
I don't see anything else I could add to the request so the there would be content apart from the parameters.

Any help would be appreciated.